# R - Is it possible to unnest a list-column that contains missing (NA) values?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, unnest

The tibble below has a list-column `property` that contains some missing values:

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl = tibble(type = c('scale', 'range', 'min', 'max'), 
         property = list(list(lttr = letters, mth = month.name), NA) %>% 
           rep(., 2))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  type  property  
  <chr> <list>    
1 scale <list [2]>
2 range <lgl [1]> 
3 min   <list [2]>
4 max   <lgl [1]>
```

I would like to unnest this column and then spread the result into a wide format with three columns - `type`, `lttr` and `mth`:

```
tbl = tibble(type = c('scale', 'range', 'min', 'max'), 
             property = list(list(lttr = letters, mth = month.name), NA) %>% 
               rep(., 2)) %>% 
  mutate(property = map_if(property, is_list, enframe)) %>% 
  unnest(property) %>%
  spread(name, value)
```

However, the `unnest` call throws the following error:

`Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [property]`

I came across a similar issue on [Git](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/436) that asks `unnest` to support `NULL` values but makes no mention of `NAs`. There don't appear to be any arguments in the function documentation that pertain to missings either, but I could be wrong.

The pipeline works as expected if the `NAs` are filtered out:

```
tbl = tibble(type = c('scale', 'range', 'min', 'max'), 
             property = list(list(lttr = letters, mth = month.name), NA) %>% 
               rep(., 2)) %>% 
  mutate(property = map_if(property, is_list, enframe)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(property)) %>% # drop_na() and na_omit not working not sure why
  unnest(property) %>%
  spread(name, value)

tbl
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  type  lttr       mth       
  <chr> <list>     <list>    
1 min   <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
2 scale <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
```

Comment: Your expected output contains 3 new columns with `max` and `range` values with all `NA`s ?

Comment: Yes, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to convert everything into `tibble` so that while `unnest`ing the structure would be the same across rather than manually subsetting

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl %>%
    mutate(property = map(property, ~ if(!is.list(.x))
        enframe(list(nm1 = .x)) else enframe(.x))) %>%
    unnest %>% 
    spread(name, value) %>%
    select(type, lttr, mth)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  type  lttr       mth       
#  <chr> <list>     <list>    
#1 max   <NULL>     <NULL>    
#2 min   <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
#3 range <NULL>     <NULL>    
#4 scale <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
```

---

The issue in the OP's example is that difference in structure for the `NA` rows when compared to the other rows.  When we `filter` them out, the structure is same across and the issue got resolved

---

We can also check with another example where the number of `list` elements are greater than 2.

```
tbl1 <- tibble(type = c('scale', 'range', 'min', 'max'), 
      property = list(list(lttr = letters, mth = month.name, 
       val1 = rnorm(12), val2 = runif(12)), NA) %>% 
        rep(., 2))

tbl1 %>% 
   mutate(property = map(property, ~ if(!is.list(.x)) enframe(list(nm1 = .x)) 
          else enframe(.x))) %>% 
   unnest %>%
   spread(name, value) %>%
   select(-nm1)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  type  lttr       mth        val1       val2      
#  <chr> <list>     <list>     <list>     <list>    
#1 max   <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>    
#2 min   <chr [26]> <chr [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
#3 range <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>     <NULL>    
#4 scale <chr [26]> <chr [12]> <dbl [12]> <dbl [12]>
```

This can be extended to arbitrary number of elements

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the structure needs to be the same for all rows. The error message was quite clear about that requirement but it didn't occur to me to use the workaround you suggested, i.e. doing `enframe(list(nm1 = .x))` for the NA rows.

Answer (score 1):

How about `unnest`ing the `tbl`, `group_by` `type` and then create new columns with `summarise` ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(lttr = property[1L], 
            mth = property[2L])

#  type  lttr       mth       
#  <chr> <list>     <list>    
#1 max   <NULL>     <NULL>    
#2 min   <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
#3 range <NULL>     <NULL>    
#4 scale <chr [26]> <chr [12]>
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround @Ronak, I wouldn't have known to use `summarise` that way.